# Swiffy banner doesn't show in non-displayed places in the page

Tags: javascript, html, flash, google-swiffy

I have several banners im my website.I changed them to Swiffy(from Flash to HTML5).The banners that appear in the top of my page, shows as needed, but other ones, that are located in the bottom of the page( need to scroll down), the banners don't appear. Does anyone know how can I fix that problem. Thank you.

Example of code :

```
<div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 549px; height: 110px"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.3.0/runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mamul.am/images/banners/vivacell3g4g-324.js"></script>

<script>
    var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'), swiffyobject, {});
    stage.start(); 
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide your codes.

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy for example this one.<div id="swiffycontainer" style="width: 549px; height: 110px"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v7.3.0/runtime.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mamul.am/images/banners/vivacell3g4g-324.js"></script>
<script>
      var stage = new swiffy.Stage(document.getElementById('swiffycontainer'), swiffyobject, {});
      stage.start();
</script>

Comment: Can anyone help please ?????

Answer (score 0):

The Swiffy runtime attempts to determine the viewport of the browser. If it can, it will only render the visible portion of the container element.

Once Swiffy considers an element to be completely outside the viewport it stops rendering completely. Unfortunately, it also stopped checking the viewport at the same time and would never render that element again, even if it was scrolled back into view.

The bug has been patched, and if it was the cause, your footer banners should play correctly now without changes.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the issue we're having ... The swiffy code is served within an iframe by DFP which we need to place in parent window .. which appears to give a blank canvas.  We've tried to re-initiate the object .. but this just throws up a bunch of js errors

We use this method various other creatives/code without any issues.